# Set the Flag in Java

Tags: java

How can set the flag to set the condition of displaying a message only once when the application gets loaded in Java Language.

Thanks,
david

Comment: You have to give more details for us to be able to help you.

Comment: Some punctuation would've been nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a global flag store, based on `enum` because we want Singleton behaviour. It could look like this:

```
public enum Flag {
    APPLICATION_LOADED(false), NEED_SAVING(true), CAN_EXIT(false) /*, ... */;

    private boolean state;
    private Flag(boolean initialState) {
      this.state = initialState;
    }

    public boolean getState() {return state;}
    public void setState(boolean state) {this.state = state;}
}
```

and use it like this

```
private void startApplication() {
  // perform startup sequence

  APPLICATION_LOADED.setState(true);
}
```

and later

```
private void showMessage(Flag flag) {
  if (flag.getState() == false) {
    // perform displaying
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I truely appreciate your effort here. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Just have a `boolean` field which you set `true` or `false` accordingly.

```
private boolean messageWasAlreadyDisplayed;
```

You can test it in an `if` statement and handle accordingly.

```
if (!messageWasAlreadyDisplayed) {
    displayMessage();
    messageWasAlreadyDisplayed = true;
}
```

#### See also:

- [Java tutorial - Primitive data types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)
- [Java tutorial - Control flow (if) statements](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just put your displaying code directly into the main method. So it executes only onces when the application is run.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this would mean only once between runs? So only on the first time it's run. This you can do by storing the flag to a file. A good starting point would be to use `java.util.Properties` which you can use for storing key-value pairs.

Something like this:

```
Properties properties = ... ; //initialize with the file 
String key = "msgAlreadyDisplayed";
if (properties.getProperty(key) == null) {
    //display the message
    properties.getProperty(key, "true");
    properties.save(....); //save to the file
}
```

Comment: In this special case, persisting might not be a good idea, because he'll need that special flag set to "false" each time the application starts. But Properties is a good starter, so +1 from my side.

Comment: @Andreas: I interpreted the question to mean that the message should be displayed only the first time the program is run. Which might be a wrong interpretation of course :)